# Use executer framework or normal thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, executors, scheduledexecutorservice

Recently I got a interview question that:

There is a scenario where one thread executing batch operation in interval of one hour will you use executer framework or normal thread and why ?

I am confused .

As there is only one thread, there is no need of executors service. I can do it using `while` 
and `sleep`.

```
while(1)
{
// do task
// t1.sleep(60*60*1000);
}
```

While there is a ScheduleExecutorService which provides so many methods for scheduulling?

What is the best way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your solution above is that if your task takes 59mins, then your thread will spend 59mins executing your task, *then* sleep for an hour. So you'll invoke your task once every (nearly) 2 hours.

If you use the scheduled executor framework, then that'll look after invoking your task every hour *on* the hour (regardless of how long it takes). Note also that it can handle the scenario in which your task executes for longer than one hour (either by design, or by accident). You can optionally opt to launch a second task in parallel, or skip the subsequent invocation.

I would generally make use of the executor framework. It provides a lot of useful functionality, and you can encapsulate your tasks such that they don't *just* have to be run in a scheduled executor, but any executor.

Comment: How it handles the scenario when the task executes for longer than one hour? Does it create extra thread?

Comment: This isn't valid if you spawn a new thread in the while block which does the actual work.

Comment: if you have java concurrency in practice book with you check the section 6.2.5.Delayed and Periodic Tasks.

Comment: @Raj I would treat that as a design issue as this is unlikely to be a good idea.

Comment: @Raj It depends on your implementation. If you only have one thread, it won't. If you spawn an extra thread in the while, you'll have another thread, but this is true regardless of using Thread or ExecutorService.

Comment: @ErikPragt I think in fact that `Timer` never goes beyond one thread; it queues up the tasks. And `ScheduledExecutorService` is fixed-size pool only. The truly flexible solution is to use `ScheduledExecutorService` as a task initiator only, which submits tasks to a flexibly configured `ExecutorService`. That's the way I have it in one of my recent projects.

Answer (score 1):

Plain thread vs. Executor Service is a false dichotomy for this case. The real question should be, use the old `Timer` vs. the new `ScheduledExecutorService`. Even on Java 1.2 it would be entirely superfluous to try to reimplement task scheduling using a plain Thread.

And the answer would again be "use the Executor Service". It's much more convenient, much more flexible and scalable. As the application grows it will be almost trivial to adapt it to ever harder requirements.

#### Timer == Oldtimer

Really, in today's Java the whole issue of Thread vs. Timer vs. ExecutorService should be stricken out as deprecated. Use ExecutorService and you can't go wrong; use any of the other options and you are painting yourself into a corner.

Comment: Why is `timer` should not used here?

Comment: Turn around your question: *why should `ExecutorService` not be used in case of a single-threaded application?* I can't think of any good reason.

Comment: Because for a very small single threaded application , using an ExecutorService could be an overhead ?

Comment: Note that the ExecutorService comes as standard. As such there's no real overhead (beyond typing an extra few chars :-) )

Comment: I support Brian's statement. There is absolutely no overhead; there *is*, however, a much more modern implementation, a better chance to get any issues fixed sooner, flexibility, customizability, scalability... you name it.

Answer (score 0):

i think that's depends on what you need.

ScheduleExecutorService has got some useful functions such as

scheduleAtFixedRate: no matter how long your task will run, this call will make sure your task run at fix rate. for example, heartbeating

scheduleWithFixedDelay: this one will add an delay after your task done, for example, some clean job.

Answer (score 0):

ScheduledExecutorService should be a good choice as you need not write the code to schedule the taks periodically. Using a well tested framework is better than writing your own framework. You can rely on ScheduledExecutorService for the periodic execution of task as configured. It will save you time and effort to write the similar functionality.

Other benefits of using ScheduledExecutorService are that you can cancel the task, can get the status of task once it is finished, etc.

Answer (score 0):

ScheduleExecutorService provides you a way to chek/cancel execution by returning ScheduledFuture. If you use a single thread, you will have to implement this yourself.